# iOs app - advertising of own applications

Tags: ios, iad

I have an iOS application with over 500K downloads so I think it's good idea put to this application banner with advertising to my another apps. And this app uses iAd.

My idea is:
- if iAd is unavailable, I will show advertising to my another apps (I will rotate 5 or 6 another banners)

- if iAd is available, I will let show 5 iAd banners, then I will show banner with advertising to one of my app and then I will show iAd (and again and again)

My question is: Is there any good practice or framework how to do this?

I thought I could use meta tag apple-itunes-app *meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL"*
in html page which I could load to the WebView (placed on the top of my application). But there could be some problems with size of WebView (I want show banner only) and with loading of "smart banner" (if I try load banner of iPad app on iPhone, page is empty. And I'm not sure if there is any way how to detect it).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your question is made up of two parts, one is detecting if iAD failed and the other is giving link to one of your apps in the app store. You can detect if iAD is unavailable in the delegate method and make your own app's banner visible there

```
-(void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
...
}
```

And you can later opt to hide your own banner in this delegate method

```
-(void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
...
}
```

To give a link to your own app I suggest you to use iOS's URL scheme. The link to your app should look like below except last 9 numbers, you can learn the app id from iTunesConnect. I would make a button with the banner as the background image and use these 2 lines inside the touch up inside event.

```
NSString *appStoreLink = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id123456789";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appStoreLink]];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's not what i meant (I know how to do this). My question is: What is the best way how to get advertising banner of own applications.